# unable to store the data in log file - NSIS

Tags: nsis

i want to add some data in the nsis log file, But when i ran the following command, it is getting executed but there is not data present in the log file.

Note : I already have the nsislog.dll file present in the plugin directory (x86-ansi & x86-unicode).

!include "MUI2.nsh"

XPStyle on

Section "Log test"

nsislog::log "c:\logfile.txt" "text to log"

SectionEnd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That plug-in only exists as ANSI, you can't just copy it to the Unicode plug-in directory and expect it to work. Luckily that plug-in is easily replaced with custom code:

```
!include Util.nsh
!define LogLine "!insertmacro WriteLineToFile"
!macro WriteLineToFile file line
Push `${line}`
Push "${file}"
!insertmacro CallArtificialFunction WriteLineToFileHelper
!macroend
!macro WriteLineToFileHelper
Exch $0
Exch
Exch $1
Push $2
FileOpen $2 $0 a
StrCmp $2 "" done
FileSeek $2 0 END
FileWrite $2 "$1$\r$\n"
FileClose $2
done:
Pop $2
Pop $1
Pop $0
!macroend


Section 
${LogLine} "$INSTDIR\install.log" "Hello"
${LogLine} "$INSTDIR\install.log" "World"
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Anders, now am able to get the log data!...